# What is the right way to setup a global hot key in MFC app?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, hotkeys

I know how to use the accelerator table to setup hot keys within my app. But how do I get a hot key at global level?

I.e. My app is running, but minimised. Yet I still want it to detect and process a hot key.

Comment: @AlexF Let me investigate that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a system-wide hotkey then you should use [`RegisterHotKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey), passing in the window handle whose window procedure is responsible for handling the event. At the application level this is commonly the `CFrameWnd`/`CFrameWndEx`-derived window implementation.

Once the hotkey is registered, the receiving window can observe the event in its custom [`CWnd::OnHotKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#onhotkey) override. Make sure to add the [`ON_WM_HOTKEY()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/wm-message-handlers-f-k) message handler to the message map of the receiving window implementation.

For a standard, default-generated SDI/MDI application you'd need to apply the following changes.

*MainFrm.h:*

```cpp
class CMainFrame : public CFrameWnd
{
    // ...
private:
    // Hot key handler routine
    afx_msg void OnHotKey(UINT nHotKeyId, UINT nKey1, UINT nKey2);
};
```

*MainFrm.cpp:*

```cpp
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainFrame, CFrameWnd)
    // ...

    // Make sure that WM_HOTKEY messages are routed to this window
    ON_WM_HOTKEY()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

// Hot key ID; can be any value in the range 0x0000 through 0xBFFF
// Allows the application to identify this hot key in case there is more than one
constexpr int MyHotKeyId = 42;

int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct) {
    // ...

    // Register a global system-wide hot key (Ctrl+Shift+Alt+I)
    if (!::RegisterHotKey(this->m_hWnd, MyHotKeyId,
                          MOD_ALT | MOD_SHIFT | MOD_CONTROL | MOD_NOREPEAT,
                          'I')) {
        auto const ec = ::GetLastError();
        auto const err_msg = std::format(L"RegisterHotKey failed (error: {})\n",
                                         ec);
        ::OutputDebugStringW(err_msg.c_str());

        // Probably a good idea to handle failure more gracefully than this:
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

void CMainFrame::OnHotKey(UINT nHotKeyId, UINT nKey1, UINT nKey2) {
    // Handle hot key; nHotKeyId is MyHotKeyId in this case
}
```

Note that receiving a `WM_HOTKEY` message grants the receiving thread [foreground activation permission](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090220-00/?p=19083). If you want your application to come to the foreground upon receiving a registered hot key, you can use the following `OnHotKey` implementation:

```cpp
void CMainFrame::OnHotKey(UINT nHotKeyId, UINT nKey1, UINT nKey2) {
    if (this->IsIconic()) {
        this->ShowWindow(SW_RESTORE);
    }
    this->SetForegroundWindow();
}
```

No flashing the taskbar button, everything just works as intended.

Comment: Thanks for the sample code. I am using a CDialog at. At the moment I register them in OnInitDialog and unregister them in OnClose. I guess OnCreate is better.

Comment: FYI I had to use `constexpr int MonitorDisplay1 = 100;`. It did not like `inline`.

Comment: I have it working well. Adjusted my code to use a lambda as I had 4 hotkeys I needed. I notice you used `m_hWnd` but I tend to use `GetSafeHwnd()`. I moved the code to `OnCreate`. Is `OnClose` the best place for unregistering? Or, don't I need to call it?

Comment: You can unregister the hot key at any time that is appropriate for your application (even from within the `WM_HOTKEY` message handler). If you want to postpone de-registration until the last possible opportunity, call `UnregisterHotKey` from your [`CWnd::OnNcDestroy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#onncdestroy) override. That's the final callback where the `m_hWnd` is still available and valid.

Comment: Do I put my unregister code before or after the `CDialogEx::OnNcDestroy`?

Comment: That doesn't really make a difference. `m_hWnd` is valid throughout the `OnNcDestroy` function. As a personal preference I'd probably unregister before calling into the base class' `OnNcDestroy` implementation, solely for reasons of symmetry, having 'objects' destroyed (or resources freed) in the opposite order they were constructed, sort of, anyway.